# switch() statement with string.contains() as parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm somewhat new to `C#` and I'm trying to create a `switch` method that returns an ID (`int`) corresponding to the given filename.

For example:

```
var fileName = "file-example_MAP_COPY.xml";
var fileTypeId = GetFileTypeId(fileName); // Returns 3310
```

With the `GetFileTypeId` method looking something like this:

```
private GetFileTypeId(string fileName)
{
    switch(string.Contains(fileName))
    {
        case ".xsd":
            return 3010;
        case "_Gui.xml":
            return 3120;
        case ".xml":
            return 3300;
        case "_MAP_COPY.xml":
            return 3310;
        ...
    }
}
```

I cannot trim the actual filename off and only keep the extension since the filename could contain underscores. A file with the name "*example_1_MAP_COPY.xml*" would be trimmed to "*_1_MAP_COPY.xml*" if trimmed at first underscore, resulting in a faulty file extension.

An `if` statement would work here, but since I have 18 different cases I'd like to find another solution than to write 18 `if` statements.

Is there some way I can go about to do this, either with a `switch` statement or a dictionary perhaps?

Comment: I think you may need to rearrange the order - case ".xml" would be found to be true & return 3300 even if the filename matched "_MAP_COPY.xml"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `switch` indeed, but it seems you are only using the end of the string, so you could use another list type to save the patterns and their outcome:

```
var l = new []
        { new { Pattern = ".xsd", Value = 3010 }
        , new { Pattern = "_MAP_COPY.xml", Value = 3310 }
        };

foreach (var p in l)
{
    if (filename.EndsWith(p.Pattern))
    {
        return p.Value;
    }
}

// not found
```

Answer (score 9):

In current C#, you can do:

```
switch(filename) {
    case string s when s.Contains(".xsd"): // or EndsWith, etc
         ...
}
```

I'm not saying that's the best approach or that it adds anything over `if`/`else if`, but... it works.

There's not much to choose between 18 complex `case` statements vs 18 `if` statements; except the `if` approach doesn't require you to add `break;` everywhere, and doesn't leak variable declarations between cases.

Personally, I'd use `if`/`else if` - or a static array of match/result pairs:

```
static readonly (string Match, int Result)[] MatchResults = new[] {
    (".xsd", 3010),
    ("_Gui.xml", 3120),
    // ...
};

...

foreach(var pair in MatchResults) {
    if(filename.Contains(pair.Match)) return pair.Result;
}
```

Comment: @EmilCarlsson there's only one way to know that: time it. But: if you can arrange the tests in hit-frequency order, that'd help; btw - take a look at the `MatchResults` suggestion I added

Comment: @ta.speot.is dictionary is useless here - they aren't equality tests; using a dictionary adds overhead without providing any useful feature

Comment: @ta.speot.is additionally: dictionary has no defined order, and these tests look to be overlapping so need to be considered in careful order; a dictionary could break the code here

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch indeed, but it seems you are only using the end of the string, so you could use a dictonary I think is simplier:

```
   private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _ids = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            {".xsd", 3010},
            {".xml", 3300},
            {"_Gui.xml", 3120},
            {"_MAP_COPY.xml", 3310}
        };

        private int GetFileTypeId(string fileName)
        {
            var element = _ids.FirstOrDefault(_ => fileName.Contains(_.Key));
            return element.Value;
        }
```

Comment: Nice one, I wonder whether an `.EndsWith` would be better or not?